# Retrieve values of a dynamic form in Android

Tags: android, listener, dynamically-generated

I created a dynamic form without much problems, but I need to recover the values from the fields (controls) of the form, but I'm not sure of how to do this.

For example, I have this piece of code:

```
if(tipoP.equals("TEXTAREA")){
   EditText ta = new EditText(this);
   ta.setId(i);
   LayoutParams params3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 0.3);
   params3.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
   ta.setLayoutParams(params3);
   ta.setLines(3);
   ta.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
   ll.addView(ta);
}
```

How do I add a listener that captures the text of the EditText and put it inside a Vector variable?

I tried this:

```
ta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view){
       EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(i);
       res.add(t.getText().toString);
   }
});
```

But I'm not getting the id (variable i) because its in another execution environment. How do I solve this? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Why would you want to capture the text when the user clicks the EditText? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a button for that?

Comment: exactly! but, this EditText is created dynamically... and when the user clicks on a button, I must get the value of this EditText and other UI components... if onClick is not the correct event which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setId for dynamically created views but `setTag` and `findViewByTag`.

Comment: But, the idea of using setId is that I'm creating several EditText and other UI components such as CheckBoxes, RadioButtons, etc... Remember, I'm talking about a form... When the user clicks on a Save button, I must obtain the values of all those UI components (as strings) and put them inside a string vector...

Comment: There is no difference basically between Ids and Tags from a functional point of view. Did you try using them ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a button dynamically and set an onClickListener on it. Inside the listener, you can just reference the EditText directly (no need for tags or ids) as long as you have made it final.